# How to translate the expression "in which"?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-requests

By *in which* I mean the saying to connect two sentences

> I destroyed the house *in which* I was born

How should it be translated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, that would be *en kiu*. Your example might be translated as

> *Mi detruis la domon en kiu mi naskiĝis.*

I imagine the *kiu* could be a *kio* or perhaps a different correlative, depending on the specific use of "which" in English.

Answer (score 3):

*Mi detruis la domon en kiu mi naskiĝis.*

*Mi detruis la domon kie mi naskiĝis.*

Ekzemploj el [Tekstaro](http://www.tekstaro.com/):

> *Mia patrolando mi nomas tiun landon, en kiu mi naskiĝis.*
>
> *Musharraf vizitis la hejmon, kie li naskiĝis.*

Comment: Ĉu "en kiu" kaj "kie" estas egalvaloraj aŭ ĉu ekzistas iu nuanca diferenco? Mi povas imagi diferencon, sed tio bazas sur mia denaska lingvo.

Comment: @Juha Metsäkallas: "en kiu" ŝajnas al mi pli konkreta kaj "kie" pli ĝenerala. En la frazo _la domon en kiu mi naskiĝis_, oni emfazas ĝuste la domon, tiun lokon ene de kiu okazis la naskiĝo. En _la domon kie mi naskiĝis_, oni ne emfazas la domon; ĝi simple estas parto de tiu loko, kie okazis la naskiĝo (oni ne emfazas la subkomprenatan ideon, ke la naskiĝo okazis en tiu domo). Sed tio estas nur mia subjektiva interpreto de la afero.

Comment: Kia koindico, ke oni diskutas pri ĉi tiu sama temo en [Lernu](https://lernu.net/eo/forumo/temo/27241).

Comment: Pri la konkreteco de _en kiu_ (Ĉar _kie_ signifas _kiuloke_.) "Tio estas la lito en kiu mi estis naskata."

Answer (score 1):

Mi uzus `kie` ĉar `en kiu`, kvankam ĝusta kaj komprenebla, senteblas nebezonate peza kaj preciza por tiu ĉi kunteksto. Jen [kelkaj ekzemploj el Tekstaro](https://tekstaro.com/?s=628e37205a228).

`kie` estas pli ampleksa kaj, por mi, natura por esprimi tion, lokon, sen devi denove mencii la aferon (`domo`, `kiu`).

Por iom klarigi la limigan flankon (kaj la pliampleksan) se oni naskiĝis sur la vojeto al domo, sed ekstere, `en kiu` rigore ne taŭgus.

`kie` havas alian avantaĝon. Ĝi povas anstataŭi en simpla maniero `en kiu`, `sur kiu`, kaj aliaj tiaj `prepozicio + afero` strukturoj, ĉar la prepozicio estas kutime evidenta aŭ konvene nedifinita (oni povas precizigi, sed kutime ne bezonatas).

Vidu ekzemplan frazon Zamenhofan, kiu povus akcepti `en kiu` sed tamen uzas la pli simplan, rektan `kie` anstataŭe:

```
Apud la budo, kie oni vendas kukojn
```

aŭ `kie` anstataŭ `sur kiu`:

```
Poste ŝi venis al granda lago, kie oni vidis nek ŝipon nek boaton.
```

Mi do dirus (sed notu ke la alia solvo ankaŭ ĝustas, kaj povus esti eĉ pli trafa, depende de tio, kion oni volas komuniki):

```
Mi detruis la domon kie mi naskiĝis.
```